# I want to make a table in React with option to export in PDF and Excel

Tags: reactjs, datatable, libraries

I'm looking for nice libraries to make a table in React, which brings information from the database and from there the tuples are formed. But in addition to that I need it to have the option to export in PDF and Excel. What dou you recommend? Thank you so much

I want free recommendations because there are many but some are premium